# NetApp use OSSV account to login through api

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, netapp

I am currently using the ManageOntap v4 SDK for NetApp devices to make snapshots to the device.  I use the OSSV snapvault commandline to do restores.

The ManageOntap api has a couple ways to login to the device.  I can do a Username\Password style, or I can use RPC style which will just login to the device using the logged in windows user.

I know OSSV uses the user (windows domain user) in the OSSV Configurator application to authenticate.

I need to login to the api using the user listed in the OSSV configurator.  This would be a windows domain user.

Anyone know if this is possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if there is some way to automatically read the credentials from the OSSV config so you don't have to enter them again? The API & Storage Controller can definitely handle Windows Domain users through both RPC (i.e. password-less) and HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: I would like to use the windows domain user in the OSSV config to authenticate through the api. I know I can read the config for the user but not sure how to pass it to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to NetApp support, the best solution was to use the NaServer.AUTH_STYLE.LOGIN_PASSWORD but pass the windows domain user that is listed in the OSSV configuration file.  Format would be domain\user.  The password would have to be supplied by the user since I can't use NaServer.AUTH_Style.RPC login style.